# What is the fastest way to perform multiple logical comparisons in R?

Tags: r, performance, logical-operators

**What is the fastest way to perform multiple logical comparisons in R?**

Consider for example the vector `x`

```
set.seed(14)
x = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size=10, replace=TRUE)
```

I want to test if each entry of `x` is either a "A" or a "B" (and not anything else). The following works

```
x == "A" | x == "B"
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The above code loops three times through the length of the whole vector. Is there a way in R to loop only once and test for each item whether it satisfies one or another condition?

Comment: how about: `x %in% c("A","B")`

Comment: @MrFlick I've been toying with timing those two options and I'm not seeing much of a difference, really. And the scale is all on nanoseconds even when I make it all bigger, so I"m a little lost.

Comment: @joran Yeah, i don't image you'd see a big speed increase (and I would highly doubt this is where any performance bottleneck is) but it's just a syntax alternative.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your objective is just to make a single pass, that is pretty straightforward to write in Rcpp, even if you don't have much experience with C++:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::LogicalVector single_pass(Rcpp::CharacterVector x, Rcpp::String a, Rcpp::String b) {
  R_xlen_t i = 0, n = x.size();
  Rcpp::LogicalVector result(n);

  for ( ; i < n; i++) {
    result[i] = (x[i] == a || x[i] == b);
  }

  return result;
}
```

---

For such a small object as the one used in your example, the slight overhead of `.Call` (presumably) masks the speed of the Rcpp version,

```
r_fun <- function(X) X == "A" | X == "B"
##
cpp_fun <- function(X) single_pass(X, "A", "B")
##
all.equal(r_fun(x), cpp_fun(x))
#[1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  r_fun(x), cpp_fun(x), times = 1000L)
#Unit: microseconds
#expr         min    lq     mean median     uq    max neval
#r_fun(x)   1.499 1.584 1.974156 1.6795 1.8535 37.903  1000
#cpp_fun(x) 1.860 2.334 3.042671 2.7450 3.1140 51.870  1000
```

But for larger vectors (I'm assuming this is your real intention), it is considerably faster:

```
x2 <- sample(LETTERS, 10E5, replace = TRUE)
##
all.equal(r_fun(x2), cpp_fun(x2))
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  r_fun(x2), cpp_fun(x2), times = 200L)
#Unit: milliseconds
#expr              min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#r_fun(x2)   78.044518 79.344465 83.741901 80.999538 86.368627 149.5106   200
#cpp_fun(x2)  7.104929  7.201296  7.797983  7.605039  8.184628  10.7250   200
```

---

Here's a [quick attempt](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/eacb0803ab7dc81bb2d8) at generalizing the above, if you have any use for it.